# Filter through Angular Collection fast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I know it's trivial but I have a doubt to be clarified. 
I have a collection `vm.groups` that has almost `1000 objects`. Now, each object has `name, id, links etc. property fields`.

Grid only displays `name and id`.

**Now, there is a text box where we enter some text and we have to filter data, according to whatever we entered but filtering must happen only within name and id fields of the objects not the other fields that are present within the objects.**

So, both things can be done,

1) I create a temp collection from the original collection objects with only name and id fields and then bind the collection to view.

```
    // vm.groups.forEach(function(element) {
    //     vm.displayedFieldGroups.
    //         push({name: element.name,id: element.id,transformedId: element.transformedId});
    // });
```

2) Or, I create a custom filter `vm.customSearch` :

```
vm.customSearch = function(searchVal) {
    if(vm.filter.length) {
        if(vm.filter.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.name.toLowerCase) !== -1 || 
        vm.filter.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.name.toLowerCase) !== -1) {
            console.log(searchVal);
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        console.log(searchVal);
        return true;
    }
};
```

And in the view `vm.groups | filter: vm.customSearch`.

But I think `second method is slower because each value in the collection would be passed to the filter which is obviously tedious for huge collection`.

Am I right?
Which is the right way to do?

**UPDATE**

This was for a legacy application. There was a filter already implemented but that just goes through all the fields in the object. I need to only filter for name and id fields of objects.

Hence, `I need to either create a custom filter or choose the first approach that I depicted.`

Comment: If you are going to use filter for (1) then why it should make any sense to over-complicate the logic and create a temporary collection? How do you want to filter items in (1) approach?

Comment: @ Stanislav Kvitash This was for a legacy application. There was a filter already implemented but that just goes through all the fields in the object. I need to only filter for name and id fields of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that the filter would go over every item in the source array and run your filter function each time there's a digest cycle.

You should proceed with the first approach.